# Else statement executing

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA programming  and currently doing some practice code via a website, I would like some clarity on below

given:

```
String str = "Jason";
str.substring(4,5);

result = "n"
```

Question:
Method `substring` parameters are `(begin_index, end_index)`.
but there is no index of 5 for variable `str` .
does JAVA automatically -1 when it comes to the length method of a string?

Comment: You might want to rename your question.  What you're asking has nothing to do with an else clause or conditional logic of any kind.

Answer (score 5):

The `substring()` method is "inclusive exclusive".

This means that in Jason, when you provided (4, 5) as parameters, it's inclusive of index 4 (n), but exclusive of index 5. Index 5 doesn't exist, but it's exclusive so it's okay.

Note that .length is NOT zero indexed. If you try to get the .length you'll get a 5. String character positions ARE zero indexed. So Jason indexed would have 0 on J and 4 on N, even though the length is 5.

Answer (score 1):

See the API documentation of [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

> Parameters:
>
> `beginIndex` - the beginning index, **inclusive**.
>
> `endIndex` - the ending index, **exclusive**.

So, what it does is take the characters in the string starting at `beginIndex` up to, but excluding, `endIndex`.

This is actually a common way to do this. An advantage of taking the begin index inclusive and the end index exclusive is that it's easy to calculate the length of the substring - it's `endIndex - beginIndex`, and you don't have to think about adding or subtracting 1 for inclusive / exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Oracle Documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29 :

Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.